# Open and Save (Overwrite) Multiple xml Files

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript

I need a Script to open all xml files in a folder and instantly save (OverWrite) a Xml File. The reason is the encoding of the XML file, I need to save in UTF-8 and resaving is the easiest way that I found.

How can I achieve this?

```
`@if (@this==@isBatch) @then
@echo off

cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" ^
        /input:"input_file.xml" ^
        /output:"output_file.xml" ^
        /from:"x-ansi" ^
        /to:"utf-8"

exit /b

@end
var adTypeText = 2;
var adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2;

var inputFile = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('input');
var outputFile = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('output');

var from = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('from');
var to = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('to');

var inputStream  = WScript.CreateObject('adodb.stream');
with (inputStream){
    Type = adTypeText;
    Charset = from;
    Open();
    LoadFromFile( inputFile );
}

var outputStream = WScript.CreateObject('adodb.stream')
with (outputStream){
    Type = adTypeText;
    Charset = to;
    Open();
    WriteText( inputStream.ReadText );
    SaveToFile( outputFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite );
}

inputStream.Close()
outputStream.Close()`
```

Comment: For an UltraEdit script solution take a look at [How to convert all files in a folder to UTF-8?](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=13855)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far too complex and convoluted.

Your principal question is simple as this progam to count words in documents in a folder shows.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\")
For Each thing in f.files
    If LCase(Right(thing.path, 3)) = "doc" Then
        Set doc = GetObject(thing.path)
                For each wd in doc.words
                    If wd = "cat" then Counter = Counter + 1
                Next
    Doc.close
    Set Doc = Nothing
    End If
Next
MsgBox Counter
```

For you use the stream `Charset` property in the loop.